# How to convert binary array to a decimal number in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I am facing difficulty in converting a binary array to a decimal number:

```
bin[8] = {10,00,00,10};
```

I want the equivalent of this array element as a decimal number, i.e. `130`.

Comment: Your array contains the decimal numbers 10 and 0. If you want a binary number you'd need to represent it as a string, or an array of bits (0 or 1 only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard solution goes like this:

```
int f(char s[])
{
    int n = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        n <<= 1;
        n += s[i] - '0';
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this code:

```
int bin_to_dec(char *src, int bits){
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        n = *(src + i) - '0';
        sum += (n * (1 << (bits - (i + 1))));
    }
    return sum;
}
```